# how to remove the gridView extra space it give between widgets - Flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview, whitespace

i am working on this flutter app where i need to show the children in a grid view, so i used a column widget in side GridView.builder like shown below, i want to remove the sapcing where its marked in the red, and leave it to be responsive somehow...
GridView widget:

```
GridView.builder(
    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      maxCrossAxisExtent: 450,
    ),
    primary: false,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
      right: 25,
      left: 25,
      top: 20,
    ),
    itemCount: data.length,
    itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
      return VideoWidget(
        oneVideoData: data[index],
      );
    },
  ),
```

VideoWidget:

```
Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              ...
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                ...                    
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
            children: [
              _videoPlayerControllerFFrame.value.isInitialized
                  ? AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio:
                          _videoPlayerControllerFFrame.value.aspectRatio,
                      child: VideoPlayer(
                        _videoPlayerControllerFFrame,
                      ),
                    )
                  : Container(
                      height: 250,
                    ),
              _isVideoLoading
                  ? const CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                    )
                  : IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (context) {
                              return VideoPlayerWidget(
                                oneVideoData: widget.oneVideoData,
                                videoController: _videoPlayerController,
                              );
                            });
                      },
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.play_arrow,
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiary,
                        size: 50,
                      ),
                    ),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 10,
            ),
            ...
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

this a screen shot of the output:

[image]

i want to get rid of the red space in the bottom.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil you mean stack widget or gridview builder, cause i used both of them

Answer (score -1):

Try below code hope its help to you.

```
GridView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
  ),
  itemCount: 6,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 5,
      shadowColor: Colors.grey,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
          10,
        ),
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: Container(
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        width: 1.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 20,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        'https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*-6WdIcd88w3pfphHOYln3Q.png',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Text('Person ${index.toString()}'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: NetworkImage(
                      'https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*-6WdIcd88w3pfphHOYln3Q.png',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                ),
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Awesome Product From Person ${index.toString()}',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Result Screen-> [image]